# Calling payable function will directly transfer eth?

Tags: solidity, transfer

It seems that calling a payable function will transfer eth directly even without explicitly calling transfer(). For example:

```
contract Storage {
    receive() external payable {}

    // Fallback function is called when msg.data is not empty
    fallback() external payable {}

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getMoney() public payable returns (bool) {
        // payable(address(this)).transfer(msg.value);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Say I have an instance of Storage is at address x. If I call getMoney() with msg.value=1, the balance of x will increase by 1, both with and without "payable(address(this)).transfer(msg.value);". Is this expected?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct. Each functions and addresses declared `payable` can receive ether.
In this case if you declare getMoney() function in this way:

```
function getMoney() public payable returns (bool) {
   return true;
}
```

and you insert a value into msg.value box (in Remix IDE) the function will to transfer the amount at address of smart contract.

More information [here](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/).

IMPORTANT: Keep in mind **payable is a modifier not a function**!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's the underlying method that actually does the transfer in getMoney() then? My concern is that transfer() and call() behave differently and the latter you also need to do a require() to prevent a reentrance attack.

Comment: The payable() modifier is the method that make the transfer of eth from your account to smart contract's address (in this case). Definitely call() function is reccomende to use because you can specify the value of gas that you're willing to pay and also you can check the value of return from this function to verify if the transaction have been correctily executed.